# Bidirectional gradient in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, gradient

I'm trying to create a gradient both in the horizontal and in the vertical direction in Sketch.

- Layering two gradient fills on top of each other, one horizontal, one vertical doesn't work: the top and left edges are not uniform
- A radial gradient doesn't work: it has a "round" shape instead of a rectangular one

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could add multiple inner shadows with a small opacity just varying the distance from the corner.

I used 10% opacity for the red and just changed the X-Y coordinates.

[image: inner shadow setup]

that's the result, probably you can refine it with more steps / more transparency:

[image: resulting gradient]

As a bonus if you create a style with it you can reuse it in any shape.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a way to achieve this without manually creating many visual layers, but I'll accept your answer if no one else has a better method :)

Comment: Btw, did you notice that the top-left corner of the gray rectangle seem to "bleed" towards the top-left corner of the red rectangle? The diagonal is definitely lighter than its surrounding area. I suppose it's a result of how the shadows merge together...

Comment: perhaps it is because of the multiple small inner shadows, if you make them larger you might get less "bleeding" - but there's a chance that right+bottom will bleed the red.